# Best approach to draw and update thousands of QGraphicsRectItem(s) efficiently?

Tags: python, performance, qt, graphics, qgraphicsview

I'm new to Qt (PySide), and I'm trying to draw a 'grid map' efficiently. However my solution slows down to a halt with 10k+ QGraphicsRectItem.

Currently it works like so:

```
class GridMapView(QObject, QGraphicsItemGroup):

def __init__(self, mapWidth, mapHeight, cellSize):
    QObject.__init__(self)
    QGraphicsItemGroup.__init__(self)

    self.mapWidth = mapWidth
    self.mapHeight = mapHeight
    self.cellSize = cellSize

    self.graphicCells = []

    #Create cells.
    for x in range(self.mapWidth / self.cellSize):
        self.graphicCells.append([])
        for y in range(self.mapHeight / self.cellSize):
            self.graphicCells[x].append(QGraphicsRectItem(x * self.cellSize, y * self.cellSize, self.cellSize, self.cellSize))
            self.graphicCells[x][-1].setBrush(QBrush(QColor('grey')))

            self.addToGroup(self.graphicCells[x][-1])

    self.setPos(-mapWidth/2, -mapHeight/2)


@Slot(Point, int)
def onCellUpdated(self, index, state):
    cell = self.graphicCells[index.x][index.y]
    if state == CellStates.UNKNOWN:
        cell.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('grey')))
        cell.setVisible(True)
    elif state == CellStates.FREE:
        cell.setVisible(False)
    elif state == CellStates.OCCUPIED:
        cell.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('black')))
        cell.setVisible(True)
```

The initial grid is populated during creation. When the appropriate signal is fired, a specific cell will be updated. This updating is fairly infrequent, and my assumption was that Qt only draws what changes.

The entire 'map' is visible in my viewport, and disabling the rendering makes my application run perfectly fine.

I've tried setting QGraphicsView.NoViewportUpdate, yet it still updates the entire view. I hoped it would require me to call '.update()'.

Is this approach flawed from the start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9122009/999943

Comment: If you're representing each cell as a separate QGraphicsItem, then yes, your method is flawed. It would be much faster to have one QGraphicsItem represent the grid and the cells internally, which is responsible for rendering all the cells in a single paint call.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight So I tried it with the single paint call, still no game. Even with caching mode enabled, it still seems to called paint()? I'm not manually calling .update() anywhere. Code using the suggested approach: [gridGraphicsItem](http://pastebin.com/T1Vz8mmY)

Comment: I suspect it's the way in which you're drawing the items that may be causing the issue now, but you've not shown that code. Be aware that calls to functions such as setBrush and setPen in the paint function will cause small delays, as the render engine gets stalled and flushed to accommodate the change.